# Best way to restructure my Object

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, object, json

So I have a object that is successfully pulling all the rows from a database and storing them like so:

```
Object {models: Array[2]}
    [Object, Object]
         0: Object
             address: "1234 Cooper"
             firstname: "Rick"
             lastname: "Bross"
             address: "1234 Cooper"
        __proto__: Object
```

How can I restructure this so I can just say:

```
alert(potentialModels.rickbross.firstname)
//rickbross = *whatever model i want to find*
```

and it output:

```
"Rick"
```

Here is how I am currently creating this object:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['username']) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `potentials`") or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = array();

    //retrieve and print every record
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // $rows[] = $r; has the same effect, without the superfluous data attribute
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    // now all the rows have been fetched, it can be encoded
    $myJSON =  json_encode(array('models' => $rows));
?>
```

and how I am getting it in the console:

```
var potentialModels = <?php print($myJSON); ?>;
console.log(potentialModels);
```

Comment: Is your `firstname + lastname` combination always unique? Also, what about `"bryant" + "hatcher"` vs. `"bryan" + "thatcher"` situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$rows[] = $r;
```

To:

```
$rows[strtolower($r['firstname'].$r['lastname'])] = $r;
```

And you can use:

```
alert( potentialModels.models.rickbross.firstname);
```

If you want to drop the `models`, stop adding it to your JSON here:

```
json_encode(array('models' => $rows));
```

By changing it to:

```
json_encode( $rows);
```

Comment: Nice Man! Thanks, one more quick question. How can I obtain all models.*modelname*.firstname into an array? I need to make a list of all the names of the potential models for the user to select.

Comment: Just loop over the `models` array, and store the `firstname` values into another array.

Comment: Will that work, since firstname isnt in potentialmodels, but its in potentialmodels.rickbross? or is there a way to target all children of potential models rather then potentialmodels.*firstname+lastname*